# laravel autoload custom folder not loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have tried to use custom folder inside `app/` to store helpers, Exceptions, Repositories etc. and i tried following to test...

**Directory Structure**

```
app
  -iw
     -Billing
         -BillingInterface.php
         -StripeBilling.php
     -Exceptions
     -Repositories
     -macros.php
```

I even added following to composer.json file and ran command `composer dump`

```
"psr-0": {
    "iw" : "app/"
}
```

classes created for testing purpose...

```
// app/iw/BillingInterface.php (location)

<?php namespace iw\Billing;

interface BillingInterface {}
```

And

```
// app/iw/StripeBilling.php (location)

<?php namespace iw\Billing;

class StripeBilling {

    public function bill()
    {
        dd('billing');
    }

}
```

When i try following...

```
(new iw\Billing\StripeBilling)->bill();
```

I get `Class 'iw\Billing\StripeBilling' not found`

Please help me resolve this. thanks

Comment: run this command composer dump-autoload

Comment: @umefarooq already tried this.

Comment: then try this PSR 4 tutorial hope this will work https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading

Comment: @umefarooq still not working using PSR 4

Comment: @umefarooq One more thing i have noticed that after running composer command, i am not seeing any update in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4`

Comment: You should run `composer dump -o` and not `composer -dump`

Comment: @tliokos yes i am running `composer dump`

Comment: @seoppc I just mentioned it because that's the way you wrote it in your post

Comment: @tliokos ah sorry it was typo and i fixed it.

Comment: What's the output from the composer after dump-autoload?

Comment: You may need to run composer self-update too, if it's not reading psr-4 directives. If not then show whole composer.json

Comment: @deczo I have updated composer by running `composer self-update`

Comment: @tliokos `Generating optimized autoload files` returned